# Working with collapse menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a website where I have a sub-menu on the left side of the page. Assume the following menu structure

```
<div>
    <li class="parent"><a style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i>Parent</a>
        <ul class="child">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></i>Child One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i>Child Two</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent"><a style="cursor: pointer;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i>Parent</a>
        <ul class="child">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet"></i>Child One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-random"></i>Child Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i>Child Three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</div>
```

I can collapse the menu no problem using `jQuery`. However, suppose a user clicks on one of the child links I would like to keep the collapsed open for only that particular parent and rest of the collapsed closed. I can't figure out how I would achieve this. Thanks in advance for your help.

This is my `jQuery` code so far.

```
$('.child').hide();
$('.parent').click(function () {
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});

$('.collapse').on('show', function (e) {
    // hide open menus
    $('.collapse').each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('in')) {
            $(this).collapse('toggle');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not over-ride `<a>` tag. And enclose the `<li>` within `<ul>` and not `<div>`. Use this way:

```js
$(function () {
  $('.child').hide();
  $('.parent > a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
  });

  $('.collapse').on('show', function (e) {
    // hide open menus
    $('.collapse').each(function () {
      if ($(this).hasClass('in')) {
        $(this).collapse('toggle');
      }
    });
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="parent"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i>Parent</a>
    <ul class="child">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></i>Child One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i>Child Two</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent"><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i>Parent</a>
    <ul class="child">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet"></i>Child One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-random"></i>Child Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i>Child Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: In my actual code it is enclosed within `ul` and not `div`. I just tried your suggestion and I can't click on the child item

Comment: Oh Shit! Yes! Lemme change it, sorry!

Comment: I can click on it now but when it goes to the child page it's the same behaviour the menu collapses whereas I want it to stay open only for that parent

Comment: any suggestions please?

Comment: You need to check for the URL and then set in JS to have the class open.

Comment: So would it be best to give each child a different class name?

Comment: Different ID would do.

Comment: Would it be possible if you can provide a example please